# SQL (DB2) - Return zero if no records found

Tags: sql, db2, sas

How can I alter this query to show zeros for each region where there are no rows found?

```
    proc sql;
create table test as
select count(acct_num) as total_count,
       region
    from
        table1
    group by region
    ;
run;
```

Ideally, I'd like to see this:

```
Region1   500
Region2   0
Region3   20
Region4   0
```

Comment: That looks like SAS code, not DB2 code - can you clarify why you tagged things the way you did?  (Though the answer is the same if you're using SQL).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a table of all the regions you want, you would use `left join`:

```
select r.region, count(t.acct_num) as total_count
from regions r left join
     table1 t
     on r.region = t.region
group by r.region;
```

If you don't have such a table, you can create one on the fly, by doing:

```
select r.region, count(t.acct_num) as total_count
from (select 'region1' as region from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      select 'region2' from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      . . .
     ) r left join
     table1 t
     on r.region = t.region
group by r.region;
```

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, DB2 supports multi-line `VALUES(...), (...)` as table references, and you don't even need to use the dummy table for this purpose.